# Multiple Server Webhosting/Databases/Etc

Tags: database, performance, web, hosting, server-side

Bit of a noob when it comes to the concept of website hosting and database hosting, especially on an international level. Sorry for the long question, I just couldn't seem to find any place that explains these things in a way that doesn't make you scratch your head and hit the 'Close Tab' button halfway through the explanation! I feel like Stack Overflow should have some kind of general guide/explanation for these things, because there are a lot of people out there like myself who can code and write web/computer/mobile applications, but still have a pretty frazzled understanding of how the basic entities of servers/hosting/websites work.

First, what I understand (and please correct me or edit this post if my understandings are wrong). I understand that one **simple, basic website**:

1. Is hosted on one server (either cloud or physical).
2. This server (on Rackspace, AWS or another webhost) allows the admin to store the website's database and accompanying server code (in Ruby/Python/PHP/etc.).
3. When a user navigates to the website, the domain is directed to the server, and the server processes and relays the information to the user based on the request.

This is simple enough, mostly because it is *one website, and one server*.

What I don't understand is how this all works when the database becomes too large to host on one computer, and you wish to maintain the website so that it is high-performance and low-latency across the world. When websites like Google, Facebook and Alibaba are accessed from the United States, India, China, etc, they relay information back to the user instantaneously. Of course, they have thousands of servers.

So here come the questions for a website that needs to be **high performance across different locales**.

1. What would such a configuration look like? Multiple servers in different locations? Would this be a mandatory configuration to maintain low latency? Or can one accomplish this with a data-center in one location?
2. What is stored on these data-center servers? Of course, the information from the website, but how so? Is the accompanying server code stored on each server separately? One server?
3. Is the database and all the accompanying information hosted on these different endpoint servers? How does the site know which server to communicate with to gather the needed data? Is there one 'entry/routing' server? How is the information maintained across several different servers in such a manner that it allows them to communicate with each other without losing precious latency time?
4. Is there one central database/data-center that feeds different data-centers/servers in different locations? Or are they spliced up and placed on several different servers? If so, how is the data maintained so that it all seamlessly stays connected?

Basically, I am having a lot of trouble envisioning *any sort of a setup that goes beyond having just one server supporting one website*.

Right now I have the familiar configuration of running a MySQL database for my website off a server in my room, and it's so simple to understand what is going on. Now I want to understand the next level, and things seem to get hazy really quickly.

Comment: I always had this question in mind too. However, I think this is kind of off-topic for SO.

Comment: Have you search about cloud system like Hunkou Amazon developed for distributed and cloud system.

Comment: I have asked a similar question in the past too. Your wording of the question is way clearer than mine was though, so +1. I hope someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think SO is definitely very useful in answering questions that are very-specific and this is what I usually use it for, but I have seen many instances on here which serve as great guides to understanding technology. A question such as this seems to address troubles in technology that many people in our community would benefit greatly from understanding, which is why I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

For databases/code hosted on multiple different physical servers, the answer to whether there is one entry/routing server would be yes.  The amount of processing done on that server can vary - from hardly anything (e.g. just a load-balancing server that forwards the request to the least-burdened server), to most of it happening on that server (with perhaps just a few database calls spread out onto different servers).

How all the servers are configured would just depend on what trade-offs the particular site had made between the performance benefits of parallelising things and the extra processing and network overhead involved in communication between the servers.

> One extreme example of distributing the load is Youtube, which
>   actually has deals with ISPs where popular videos are stored on the
>   ISP's servers for quicker access.  I don't know how it works exactly
>   but it's possible that the ISP then just intercepts the request for
>   those videos, sends them back to you and the Youtube servers are never
>   involved at all.

^ I wrote the above and then tried to find the original link I read it on and couldn't, so I don't know whether it's true - can someone verify this?